# exec in nodejs not getting string shellscript path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am new to NodeJs.. To run shellscript file from electron app i have used child_process package from nodejs.
When we give absolute path to exec then it works fine. but if we store absolute path in some variable and pass that variable to exec it shows "no such file or directory" error.

```
//In this case it works fine due to absolute path provided
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;

    var scriptFile = exec('sh --Here is absolutepath--/demoScript.sh');

    scriptFile.stdout.on('data', function(data){
         console.log(data); 
    });

    scriptFile.stderr.on('data', function(data){
       console.log(data);
    });
```

But if we create var of absolute path it shows error

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require("path");

var absolutePath = path.resolve('../.././demoScript.sh');
var scriptFile = exec('sh absolutePath');

   scriptFile.stdout.on('data', function(data){
       console.log(data); 
   });

   scriptFile.stderr.on('data', function(data){
      console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: If this `'../.././demoScript.sh'` is the actual path, try removing the dot before the last forward slash.

Comment: Also here `exec('sh absolutePath');` I would do something like `exec('sh' +
 absolutePath);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here `var scriptFile = exec('sh absolutePath');`
The `exec` function takes a `string` as an argument. So in your case it is literally executing `absolutePath` instead of the value tha `absolutePath` has.
Try this, rather

```
var toExec = 'sh ' + absolutePath;
var scriptFile = exec(toExec);
```

Also, should this not work, then the problem is with `sh`. You do not need it, as the exec function will simply execute whatever path you provide.

Comment: i tried but now it showing no such file or directory error

Comment: remove `sh` and rather do `var scriptFile = exec(absolutePath);`

Comment: your solution is working now, just problem is that how do i get absolute path??
Because var absolutePath = path.resolve('../../demoScript.sh'); this line gives me path depends on how much '../ ' i have used.

Comment: I'm glad the solution worked. Please consider voting an answer up or considering it as an accepted answer when it has worked for you. Getting the absolute path is  separate and different question from what you asked above